# Need software-based, resonant filter for 90's ROMpler

Tags: midi, synthesizer, keyboard, filter, modulation

Any suggestions on how to add a resonant filter to a keyboard that does not have one?

I have a Alesis Quadrasynth (QS4) and want to do midi-triggered filter sweeps in real-time.

Thank you!

Dan

Comment: Could you provide more information about your setup? What DAW? Any available audio inputs on your audio interface? Do you already have filter plugins?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I just started using Ubuntu Studio (calfJACK Host looks promising), but much of the software options are new to me. I have been using PC with Windows XP with Line6 TonePort & Sound Blaster Live! Drive, Sonar (1st version), Anvil, Caustic3, MidiOx, MidiYoke, and Sound Forge. Keyboard is Quadrasynth. I also have a MMT-8 sequencer.

Comment: I have not used any filter plugins. Both sound cards have audio inputs, keyboard has 2 main outs and 2 auxillary outs.

Comment: My version of Sonar can only use DirectX plugins. I am open to trying a new DAW and am looking at Ardour3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a free vst called north pole that can follow the envelope of the audio through it

http://blog.wavosaur.com/the-5-best-free-vst-filters/

Answer (score 0):

I have heard wonderful things about this box: http://www.sherman.be/index.php/products/filterbank

If you are comfortable with circuits (or learning) it wouldn't be especially hard to build your own midi-controllable filter with an Arduino.  The schematics of a moog ladder filter are widely available.

You can try looking at a Guitar FX pedal as well.